# dSYM files for release builds

Tags: ios, gcc4, dwarf, symbolicate

Do `.dSYM` resources contain any other information except DWARF information? I have created a release build of an app. Now if I run `dwarfdump` on it, it says the executable has no DWARF info (says it's "empty"), which is what I would expect. But if I then run `dsymutil` on it, it creates non-empty symbol files. These are binary files so I don't know what's in them. Can anyone enlighten me on this? Are there any viewers for these files?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is additional information. Note that the .dSYM file is actually a directory. Inside you will find:

```
SomeApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist
SomeApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SomeApp
```

Be aware that you need to keep the exact `.dSYM` and `.app` bundle that was created when you made the release build. Even if the code hasn't changed, the `.dSYM` from a separate build won't match up because apple generate a unique id for each build you do.